# JavaScript to add sliced images to div automatically

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to stackoverflow and really hope you guys can help me. I designed a small website for a photographer and he is not okay with the options for his images being download. I know that there is no way to secure images online. (You can easily just save page and get everything you need). *if there is a better way. Please kindly let me know..*
So anyway i said i will slice his images and upload so people will be downloading only pieces of his image. Even though it is not 100%n secure, he was okay with it after several explanation hours :)
I was hoping to used SuperSimple image tiles but since it runs php alot, it is a bit slow to load images. Im sure, you guys are aware of it.
So anyway now im hoping to use a batch image slicer and slice the images. oh i forgot to tell, there are around 100 images :D
So anyway, i will equally slice an image to 25 pieces (5x5). and i will be adding the image full complete inside a div. What i need to know is, is there away to add the sliced images with a js loop so the process will be much smoother and simpler. Since the div will resize according to the screed dimensions, full image should be in 100% width and height.

this is the current full image syntax.

```
<div> <img src="IMAGE (1).jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> </div>
```

What i want to do is, instead of image tag above, i need to run a loop script. to add 25 images (instead of 1 image to make an image tile).
images are named as IMAGE (1)1, IMAGE (1)2, IMAGE (1)3..etc.. till IMAGE (1)25 and the again IMAGE (2)1,  IMAGE (2)2, IMAGE (2)3..etc.. till IMAGE (2)25...

Hope i explained my problem well. Please someone let me know an easy way to add a script to automate the image inserting process. i believe Image style should be as FLOAT=LEFT and WIDTH=20% and HEIGHT=20%..

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The trick I was using was to use a simple flash container that received a "semi crypted" was actually a rotate13 (shift each letters 13 letters  from alphabet, so doing it again would convert back to normal) and use that to find the image and display it. So people could not just right click and save as... But it is never 100% safe of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP will be better for one important reason: not everyone has javascript enabled.
I'm not familiar with 'SuperSimple image tiles' so I can't comment on its performance but plain php will not slow it down compared - in most situations it should be faster than a similar javascript loop just due to the fact that it is on less piece of data to download to the client side.

To do that in plain php (assumptions spelled out in the initial variables and that the image chunk numbering starts at 0):

```
<?php
$img_path =  "images/funkytree_" //the base image path without the number or the extension
$img_ext = ".jpg" //the extension
$img_alt =  "funky tree" //alt text for the images
$i = 0;
while ($i < 25) {
echo "<img src='{$img_path}{$i}{$img_ext}' alt='{$img_alt}'/>;
$i ++;
}
?>
```

Then best would be to use CSS styling to set the position/size of each image.

HTH
Nick